# Default Ship-To address to warehouse location when customer ship-to is not available, for Cash Sales

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

For custom cash sales form, is there a way or is there a suitescript, that will default the ship-to address with the company warehouse location, when the customer ship to address does not exist or is null?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the end-use.

Proper way: You'd have to create a custom address on the customer whenever the case applies, then link back this to the SO.

Less proper way: Create an address entry on the customer for each company, when the customer is created, this is easier but more messy.

Comment: Thanks. I'm sorry to hear that there is no approved, standard and easy  way to default a ship to in NetSuite.

Comment: Does NetSuite have the ability to default the shipping method for cash sale trans to Pick Up location?

Comment: I found some info on setting up a default ship-to. The option they describe is in the setup of a location code. They explained that if we want the ship to to default to the origin, we can check on the Pick Up Location check box. However; when I view, edit, or create a new location, I do not see the Pick Up checkbox available. How do I enable the Pick Up location check box for location code setup?